What is the best way to access immutable part when subclassing immutable type?
Suppose that you want to create a new subclass for float, using the following code:
class MyFloat(float):
    def __new__(cls,number,extra):
        return super().__new__(cls,number)

    def __init__(self,number,extra):
        float.__init__(number)
        self.extra = extra

This, from what I understand, is good practice for this part of the class. And if we stop here, then for x=MyFloat(0.0,'hi'), then x+1 will evaluate to 1.0 (as a float), as expected.
Now, suppose that we want it to instead return a MyFloat equal to MyFloat(1.0,'hi'). A first pass thought would be to add
    def __add__(self,other):
        return MyFloat(self+other,self.extra)

but of course, if you try this, it will result in a recursion error, as it calls itself. (yes, I'm aware that adding two MyFloats will have only the first one's extra, this is basically a minimal example of what I'm asking).
There are a few obvious ways to handle it, but they all feel very hacky. There's the conversion to float:
    def __add__(self,other):
        return MyFloat(float(self)+other,self.extra)

or calling float.__add__ instead of using +, as:
    def __add__(self,other):
        return MyFloat(float.__add__(self,other),self.extra)

Is there a "more pythonic", or perhaps more efficient, way to handle this kind of thing?
And what if I want to access the immutable part in another context? For example, if I want the extra part to be updated to f"{self+1.0}" for some reason, where self here is the immutable part, how do I get that part set up?
Update: I've done a bit of speed testing, and I've found something interesting. Using float.__add__ (or super().__add__) is relatively slow, typically taking more than 20% more time than my baseline code (which performs all of the same calculations, etc, but takes the inputs as separate parts, rather than as a single variable). Casting to float with float(self) and float(other) does better, typically around 15% slower than the baseline. It's about 12% slower than baseline to do self.real and other.real, which improves further...
Strangely, the fastest approach I've found is to use +self and +other - this gets it down to around 6-8% slower than baseline. I'm not sure why it's faster than float(self), since from what I can tell, the underlying code should basically be exactly the same, but it's quite consistent.
I'd be interested to know whether anyone knows a more efficient approach than this.

there's nothing really hacky, you are bascially using new_float_obj = super().__add__(self, other) inside of __add__, and then returning MyFloat(new_float_object, ....) This is fine. Although, are you sure you really want to subclass float?

Either of the methods you laid out are fine.  I think the explicit conversion is easier to read.

I would consider using super().__add__ (an super().__init__) instead of hardcoding the reference to float. You're already using super in __new__, so you should be consistent.

May I ask why you want to use inheritance instead of composition? What is the "extra" really? As it stands this doesn't sound much like a float subtype, it seems like something else entirely.

@wim - I'm trying to generalise dual numbers in a particular way for a specific application - I won't go into too much detail here. I want to use inheritance from float so that functions not designed for my subtype will still work with the base float value automatically. That being said, the composition approach seems to be a little faster (and, interestingly, implementing the operation as __add__ ends up faster than doing it with a normal method)

@chepner - oddly, after some testing of different combinations, I've found that super().__new__ and float.__init__/float.__add__ is marginally, but consistently, faster than alternative combinations (such as float for all three or super() for all three). Not sure why.
